# How to convert array string to an array in python

Tags: python, mysql, arrays

Im trying to convert an array that ive stored in a mysql database (as a string) to a standard array in python an example of what I mean is:

This is what i get from the database:

```
"['a',['b','c','d'],'e']" # this is a string in the format of an array that holds strings inside it.
```

I need to remove the array from the string so that it acts just like a normal array
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if this has been answered elsewhere, sorry if it has I couldn't find it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) in the `ast` module

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = "['a',['b','c','d'],'e']"
>>> print(literal_eval(s))
['a', ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'e']
```

Comment: while this is definately right(+1) ... he may want to consider changing the format that he is storing in the db to json or something

Comment: @JoranBeasley Do you know how i would use python to store json in the database

Comment: @RileyThe15YearOld `json.dumps()` will turn your array into a JSON string, and `json.loads()` will turn it back into a Python array.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense id just prefer to keep it as an array really

Comment: @RileyThe15YearOld ok, but it's not going to be as reliable or safe, I don't think.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense all it is to do it store menu options for a website so it should be ok

Answer (score 12):

If you can convert those single quotes to double quotes, you can use json parsing.

```
import json
obj1 = json.loads('["a", ["b", "c", "d"], "e"]')
```

Comment: The accepted answer is a better solution.

Comment: This one also good solution.

Comment: I think your solution is better.