# How to transform python string into array

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

a python string:

```
'[[4,2],[8,5]]'
```

for example, where you have a fairly complex multidimensional array of information, maybe is extracted from a file or user input and is naturally a string. How should I go about turning this into an actual array. I want a general implementation so that I can perform this to any multidimensional and complex array. This is for a machine learning project, and any of these arrays can be represented with a shape (e.g. `(3,2,5)` ) and a list of its corresponding values (e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]` ) such that is may look like:

```
[[[1,2,3,4,5],
  [6,7,8,9,0]],
 [[1,2,3,4,5],
  [6,7,8,9,0]],
 [[1,2,3,4,5],
  [6,7,8,9,0]]]
```

Comment: You can execute code with `eval` e.g. `a = eval('[[4,2],[8,5]]')`

Comment: This is a duplicate question: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572247/how-to-convert-array-string-to-an-array-in-python

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `neural-network` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
def flatten_list(_2d_list):
    flat_list = []
    for element in _2d_list:
        if type(element) is list:
            for item in element:
                flat_list.append(item)
        else:
            flat_list.append(element)
    return flat_list

nested_list = [[4,2],[8,5]]

print(nested_list)
print(flatten_list(nested_list))
```

Comment: Notice that in OP's question the list expression is actually a *string*; it is `'[[4,2],[8,5]]'`, not `[[4,2],[8,5]]`.

Comment: ooops......then we can use string.split() method on '[[4,2],[8,5]]' to convert to string. can we?

Comment: Well, why don't you try it? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
array = np.array(list)
array = np.reshape(array, (3,2,5))
```